# How can I allow fail build on lint errors and generate lint report as well for android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gitlab-ci, lint

I'm trying to integrate lint on gitlab ci for android kotlin. Right now when I have lint issues it fails the build but doesn't generate lint reports.

How can I allow fail build on lint errors and generate lint report as well for android kotlin?

Trying to linter for android kotlin on gitlab CI expecting build to fail on lint errors as well as generate lint reports.

Comment: Can you share relevant parts of your CI job configuration file?

Comment: Hi `script: - echo "lint stage" - gradle clean lintDebug` . this is what I'm running as part of my script, Need an option on gradle , nothing to do with gitlab I think

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `allow_failure`

> Allow job to fail. A failed job does not cause the pipeline to fail.

```
  image: your image
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  script:
-
```

Comment: Hey I want an option to fail the gradle lintDebug and generate report as well. I'm not looking for an option to continue with other stages when this job fails.